# how can I set the value of objectId to another property different that _id when creating a document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create an object that looks like this:

```
const userSettingsSchema = extendSchema(HistorySchema, {
  user: //ObjectId here,
  key:{type: String}, 
  value:{type: String} 
});
```

this is the post method declared in the router

```
app.post(
  "/api/user/settings/:key",
  userSettingsController.create
);
```

and this is the method "create":

```
async create(request, response) {   
  try {
    const param = request.params.key;
    const body = request.body;
    console.log('body', body)
    switch (param) {
      case 'theme':
        var userSettings = await UserSettings.create(body) // user:objecId -> missing...
        response.status(201).send(userSettings);
        break;
    }

  } catch (e) {
    return response.status(400).send({ msg: e.message });
  }
}
```

I don't know how to assign the value of `ObjectId` to the `user` property, because `ObjectId` is generate when the doc is created, thus, I can not do this: userSettings.user = userSettings._id, because the objectr is already. I only manage to get something like this created:

```
{
    "_id": "60c77565f1ac494e445cccfe",
    "key": "theme",
    "value": "dark",
}
```

But it should be:

```
{
    "user": "60c77565f1ac494e445cccfe",
    "key": "theme",
    "value": "dark",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

_id is the only mandatory property of a document. It is unique identifier of the document and you cannot remove it.

If you provide document without _id the driver will generate one.

You can generate ObjectId as

```
let id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
```

and assign it to as many properties as you want.

You can even generate multiple different ObjectIds for different properties of the same document.

Now, you don't really need to assign ObjectId to "user" property. _id will do just fine. In fact it is most likely you don't need user's settings in separate collection and especially as multiple documents with single key-value pair.

You should be good by embedding "settings" property to your "user" collection as a key-value json.